# Meteor webpack fails to resolve npm package

Tags: meteor, build, webpack

I'm installing Meteor webpack package (https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack) and the build is failing on npm modules. More precisely, it cannot resolve the path of the `package.json` that are loaded with `require('./package')`. It seems to look at `package/package.json` instead of `package.json`:

```
Errors prevented startup:                  
   While processing files with webpack:webpack (for target os.osx.x86_64):
   src/server.js: ./~/juice/index.js
   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./package in
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice
   resolve file
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package doesn't exist
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.js doesn't exist
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.jsx doesn't exist
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.css doesn't exist
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.less doesn't exist
   resolve directory
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package doesn't exist (directory default file)
   pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package/package.json doesn't exist (directory description
   file)
   [pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package]
   [pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.js]
   [pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.jsx]
   [pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.css]
   [pathToProject/node_modules/juice/package.less]
   @ ./~/juice/index.js 15:18-38
```

Here is a change that makes a project fails:  https://github.com/gsabran/kickstart-meteor-react-flowrouter/commit/7249fe4a92429b0cff9ef8152559dc323b1f403b

Is there something that is not done right, or is it an issue with webpack / Meteor webpack?